# onReceive in BroadcastReceiver triggers when app starts

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I was making a sample and spotted that if i register receiver in code onReceive triggers when app starts. But if i register one in the context it doesn't Why?

```
Activity:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("SomeString");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mBroadcastReceiver = new SomeReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,new IntentFilter("DanMan"));
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
}
```

}

Receiver:

```
public class SomeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("receiver", "action :" + intent.getAction());
    intent.setAction("DanMan");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent.putExtra("SomeString", "Hello world!"));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this and let me know if it works or not

1. Just create a BroadcastReceiver Object before onCreate using

> ```
> private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver;
> ```

2. Instantiate the register object in onCreate() using

> ```
> mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
>     @Override
>     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>         String message = intent.getExtras().getString("SomeString");
>         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }
> };
> ```